# Extract data from salesforce object within an email on MC

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, triggered-send

i want to send a welcome email to new subscribers using a triggered send, in my email (classic content) this is my code but it doesn't work; i get no email address when i signup. Is it a match problem? knowing that only this mapping allow the trigger to work.

```
%%[ var @res,  @eRow, @FirstName ,@PersonEmail, @Id <br>
set @res = RetrieveSalesforceObjects("Account","FirstName, PersonEmail", "PersonEmail","=",@PersonEmail) <br>
set @eRow = Row(@res, 1) <br>
set @FirstName= Field(@eRow, "FirstName") <br>
set @PersonEmail= Field(@eRow, "PersonEmail")<br>
]%%
```

Any help ? thank you

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure why you've included `<br>` tags. Perhaps it's a copy and paste issue?

Anyway, you haven't set `@PersonEmail` anywhere, so this won't work. Also, I'd encourage you to make your code more resilient as if no results are returned then you will get an error. I'd change your code to something like this:

```
%%[ 
var @res, @eRow, @FirstName ,@PersonEmail, @CountRows
set @PersonEmail = AttributeValue('PersonEmail') /* change as required */
set @res = RetrieveSalesforceObjects("Account","FirstName, PersonEmail", "PersonEmail","=",@PersonEmail) 
set @CountRows = RowCount(@res)
   if @CountRows > 0 then
    set @eRow = Row(@res, 1)
    set @FirstName= Field(@eRow, "FirstName") 
    set @PersonEmail= Field(@eRow, "PersonEmail")
   endif
]%%
```

Comment: Thak you for your answer, yess the <br> was a copy paste error, i tried the code and it's still not working ..

Comment: How have you set `@PersonEmail`?

Comment: you mean the output ?  %%=v(@PersonEmail)=%%

Comment: How are you setting `@PersonEmail`? I can't see the code where you set `@PersonEmail` — the code that I provided was just an example. You will need to set `@PersonEmail` first. But perhaps you already are. If you print that variable `%%=v(@PersonEmail)=%%` do you see anything?

Comment: it is set @PersonEmail = AttributeValue("PersonEmail"), and the fiels on the received emails are empty, but i have no code errors detected

Comment: It's a bit challenging to figure out what you are doing here. Let's take this off the comment thread — can you [propose up a time](https://calendly.com/eliot-harper/30min/) for a webinar so I can review your setup.

Comment: Thank you i guess it's better, this is my email address: sarah.bezi@edifixio.com, i'm paris based, available from 10am to 6pm.

Comment: Hi @SarahBezi please select a time from the link I provided. Thanks!